# How to test H0 that two coefficients associated with dummy variables of same categorical variable are equal?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, regression-coefficients, categorical-encoding, contrasts

I have a variable $X$ which I predict with a nominal categorical variable $Y$ with category labels $\{0,1,\dots,m \}$ using a linear model. I use standard dummy coding which gives me the regression equation

$$
X = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \mathbb{I}_{Y=1} + \beta_2 \mathbb{I}_{Y=2} + \dots + \beta_m \mathbb{I}_{Y=m}
,
$$

where $\mathbb{I}_{K}$ is the indicator function for the event $K$.

Since $Y=0$ is the reference categories, the standard errors I get for all $\beta_1, \beta_2, \dots \beta_m$ give me a test for the contrast of category 0 with all the other categories.

However, I'm interested in all pairwise comparisons. Of course I could get all those contrasts by running $m$ regression models, in each of which I make another category the reference category. However, I am wondering whether there is a way to get all contrasts out of the single model above with reference category $0$? That was the motivation for the question in the title about testing the H0 that two parameters associated with dummy coded variables, let's say $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ are the same.

Comment: In `R` the `emmeans` package makes this [easy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/comparisons.html#pairwise). The concrete implementation depends on the software you're using. The model you're describing seems to be analogous to a one-way ANOVA.

Comment: What would be your null and alternative hypotheses? It seems like the usual ANOVA answers your question, but I could be wrong about what question you want to ask.

Comment: formulate a [tag:contrasts] on your coefficients (maybe add that tag) and test the contrast. That is probably what *emmeans* helps you to do